# NoneType error with lists in a while loop?

Tags: python

I'm writing a guessing game program, with defined functions. It asks the user to think of a number between 1 and 1000, then the program tries to guess the number in less than 15 tries. With my functions, to return multiple values in each function, I'm returning them as lists. But there's a NoneType error - here's the error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 187, in <module>
  File "python", line 167, in main
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Here's my code:

```
while opAns.lower() != "no":
    FBTrcTri = guessReturn(tries, upper, lower)
    feedback = FBTrcTri[0]
    errorBound = FBTrcTri[1]
    errorTrick = FBTrcTri[2]
    tries = FBTrcTri[3]
```

And the function is defined here:

```
def guessReturn(tries, upper, lower):
    while tries < 15:


        errorInput = "yes"

        while errorInput == "yes":
            feedbackGuessVal = guesser(upper, lower)


            feedback = feedbackGuessVal[0]
            guessVal = feedbackGuessVal[1]


            LUITri = processData(feedback, tries, upper, lower, guessVal)


            lower = LUITri[0]
            upper = LUITri[1]
            errorInput = LUITri[2]
            tries = LUITri[3]


            errorBound = boundChecker(upper, lower)
            errorTrick = trickChecker(upper, lower)

            if errorBound == "yes":
                return
            elif errorTrick == "yes":
                return
            elif feedback == "0":
                tries += 1
                return


        tries += 1


    return [feedback, errorInput, errorBound, errorTrick, tries]
```

Comment: There are plenty of instances in your `guessReturn` function where you return nothing/`None`, i.e. `return`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if errorBound == "yes":
    return
elif errorTrick == "yes":
    return
elif feedback == "0":
    tries += 1
    return
```

A `return` statement with no value will return `None`, which you are then trying to treat as a list

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you that you are trying to use subscription syntax (`[...]`) on an object with the type `NoneType` (i.e. the `None` singleton object).

Your `guessReturn()` function returns `None` in several places:

```
if errorBound == "yes":
    return
elif errorTrick == "yes":
    return
elif feedback == "0":
    tries += 1
    return
```

`return` with no explicit return value returns `None`.

You are trying to subscribe on that result with:

```
feedback = FBTrcTri[0]
```

You'll either have to explicitly test if `FBTrcTri` is `None` (or use exception handling to catch the `TypeError`), or return at least 4 values in a list or tuple *always*, from all exit points of your function.